# Angular call two promises in chain with the result of the firts

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm still having troubles with Angular promises. I have three factories: `getPosition`, which obviously gets current position, `geoCode`, which uses google's reverse geocoding to get the name of the city, and `getData`, which gets some data from API depending on the position. I need to call `geoCode` and `getData` right after I get the position. I managed to chain `getPosition` and `geoCode` like this:

```
getPosition.get().then(function(geoInfo){
      $scope.$storage.geoInfo = geoInfo;
      return geoCoding.getFromObj(geoInfo).then(function(city){
        $scope.$storage.city = city;
        $scope.city = $scope.$storage.city;
      },function(reason){
        alert("Geocoding error: " + reason);
      })
    }, function(reason){
      alert("Location error: " + reason);
    });
```

How do I add the call to `getData` into the chain so that it is called with the data of the first call to? I tried something like this :

```
getPosition.get().then(function(geoInfo){
      $scope.$storage.geoInfo = geoInfo;
      return  function(geoInfo){
        geoCoding.getFromObj(geoInfo).then(function(city){
        $scope.$storage.city = city;
        $scope.city = $scope.$storage.city;
      },function(reason){
        alert("Geocoding error: " + reason);
      });
        getData.getFromObj(geoInfo).then(function(data){
          $scope.$storage.data=data;
        })
      }
    }, function(reason){
      alert("Location error: " + reason);
   });
```

But both `geoCoding` and `getData` don't work this way. Also most tutorials/ articles on the internet explain how to chain calls one after another, but I couldn't find anything explaining how to chain them like i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried like this:

```
getPosition()
  .then(function(pos){
     return getGeoCoding(pos); // should return promise
   })
  .then(function(geo){
     return getData(geo); // should return promise
   })
  .then(function(data){
     // do stuff with data
   })
  .catch(function(err){  // falls to this if any of the above fails
    //console err 
   });
```

It's just a principle, but you get the point.